# Get ratings for an item via API - Podio

Tags: api, rating, podio

I'd like to get information about a rating (*fivestars*) of one of an app item.
I've tried to do it using two requests:

```
/rating/item/1********9
```

and

```
/item/1********9?mark_as_viewed=false
```

Both via `https://developers.podio.com/`.

I'm receiving only the response (related to ratings):

```
"ratings":{
   "like":{
      "average":null,
      "counts":{
         "1":{
            "total":0,
            "users":[
               
            ]
         }
      }
   }
},
```

In the GUI I can see my vote (3 stars).

Could you please help me with how I could get the rating?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a star rating to a Podio app is actually creating a Voting object (I know it's not very intuitive). I believe the endpoint you're looking for is [Get result of voting on an item](https://developers.podio.com/doc/voting/get-results-of-all-applications-votings-on-an-item-117727936).